# Lots of socket errors with celery eventlet tasks

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, eventlet

I'm getting a lot of "IOError: Socket closed" exceptions from amqplib.client_0_8.method_framing.read_method when running my celery workers with the --pool=eventlet option. I'm also seeing a lot of timeout exceptions from  eventlet.hubs.hub.switch.

I'm using an async_manage.py script similar to the one at https://gist.github.com/821848, running the works like:

```
./async_manage.py celeryd_detach -E --pool=eventlet --concurrency=120 --logfile=<path>
```

Is this a known issue, or is there something wrong with my configuration or setup?

I'm running djcelery 2.2.4, Django 1.3, and eventlet 0.9.15.

Comment: are you sure your tasks don't do blocking calls?

Comment: I'm monkey patching every, but I'm not 100% certain that nothing is blocking. What's the best way to find out, and what can I do if they are?

Comment: monkey patching only patches what eventlet knows how to patch, so you could still use libraries that are not covered by that.  See here for example: http://unethicalblogger.com/2010/08/28/unclog-the-tubes-blocking-detection-in-eventlet.html

Comment: I've enabled blocking detection and it occasionally blocks at "return self.connection.commit()" in django/db/backends/__init__.py - I'm using MySQL. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Discovered the undocumented MySQLdb option to monkey_patch - doing more testing now!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was a side effect of some code that was blocking. I managed to detect the blocking code using the eventlet option described [in this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20111010194145/http://unethicalblogger.com/2010/08/28/unclog-the-tubes-blocking-detection-in-eventlet.html).

There were 2 places where blocking was occuring: DNS lookups, and MySQL database access. I managed to resolve the first by installing the dnspython package, and the second my using the undocumented MySQLdb option in eventlet:

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()
eventlet.monkey_patch(MySQLdb=True)
```